# Is it possible to run XAMPP on a CD?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have a laravel project which I would like to make portable with a CD. Is XAMPP just a simple install as normal?

Comment: Refer :  https://willtan.com/installing-xampp-on-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: Why a CD???? USB is much more ubiquitous. A CD will be painfully slow for all read operations and good luck writing logs...

Comment: Go for https://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp